# How to split a String with multiple delimiters in Java

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I am trying to have the desired outputs like this:

```
555
555
5555
```

by using codes:

```
public class Split {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String phoneNumber = "(555) 555-5555";

    String[] splitNumberParts = phoneNumber.split(" |-");


    for(String part : splitNumberParts)
        System.out.println(part);
```

But dont know how to get rid of the "( )" from the first element.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried adding them to the string of delimiters?

Comment: have you checked with pattern and matcher classes? Once you know them you can write regular expression for extracting what you need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) supports multiple delimiters that can be listed in a string as second parameter.

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(phoneNumber, "()- ");
String a = tok.nextToken();
String b = tok.nextToken();
String c = tok.nextToken();
```

In your case, this will give a = 555, b = 555, c = 5555.

Comment: how to put all the outputs into an array in this case please ?

Comment: String [] elements = new String[tok.countTokens()], then just use for loop to iterate over tokens.

Answer (score 4):

why not do a replace first?

```
String phoneNumber = "(555) 555-5555";
String cleaned = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]",""); // "5555555555"
```

Then you can use substring to get the parts you want.

Comment: I'd prefer this solution as it doesn't require exact source formatting, giving more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your digits in sequence, then you can probably make use of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class, to find all the substrings matching a particular pattern, in your case, `\d+`.

You would need to use [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method to get all the substrings matching your pattern. And use [`Matcher#group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) to print the substring matched.

Here's how you do it: -

```
String phoneNumber = "(555) 555-5555";

// Create a Pattern object for your required Regex pattern
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

// Create a Matcher object for matching the above pattern in your string
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);

// Use Matcher#find method to fetch all matching pattern.
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using split java will return an array of string which is separated from where there was an occurence of the items which you provided, thus if you where to do a split like you are doing now, you could add something like this:

```
phoneNumber.split(" |-|\\(|\\) ");
```

But thats not very nice looking, now is it? So instead we can do something like this, which basically tells java to remove anything that isn't a number:

```
String[] splitNumberParts = phoneNumber.split("\\D+");
```

Comment: in your case, the first element in the array would be " " (space)